# PopBackStack вызывает OnCreateView каждый раз

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

У меня есть два фрагмента. Первый - фрагмент с recyclerview и поисковым текстовым полем:

[image: Главный фрагмент]

Как видите, при запуске приложения, открывается этот фрагмент и загружаются дефолтные картинки.
Если что-то ввести в поисковой строке, то будет произведён поиск и в recyclerview загрузятся картинки, соответствующие словам в поиске:

[image: Поиск]

```
class FragmentMain : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mService: RetrofitServices
    private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager
    private lateinit var adapterOne: OneAdapter
    private lateinit var adapterTwo: TwoAdapter
    lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
    lateinit var switchCompat: SwitchCompat
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var editText: EditText
    lateinit var labels: Labels
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    var fragment: FragmentMain = this
    lateinit var stateHelper: FragmentStateHelper

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        switchCompat = view.findViewById(R.id.customSwitch)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerPictures)
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_search)
        mService = Common.retrofitService
        labels = Labels()
        stateHelper = FragmentStateHelper(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
        dialog = SpotsDialog.Builder().setCancelable(true).setContext(context).build()
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
           getAllPicturesList(savedInstanceState.getString("key")!!)
        } else {
            getAllPicturesList(editText.text.toString())
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Search is: " + editText.text.toString())
        switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (switchCompat.isChecked) {
                setOneAdapter(labels)
            } else {
                setTwoAdapter(labels)
            }
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getAllPicturesList(editText.text.toString())
        } else {
           stateHelper.restoreState(this, "key")
        }
        editText.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener{
            override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                if (keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    getAllPicturesList(editText.text.toString())
                    return true
                } else{
                    return false
                }
            }
        })
        return view
    }

    private fun setOneAdapter(labels: Labels) {
        adapterOne = OneAdapter(context, labels)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapterOne
        adapterOne.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun setTwoAdapter(labels: Labels) {
        adapterTwo = TwoAdapter(context, labels)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapterTwo
        adapterTwo.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun getAllPicturesList(search: String) {
        dialog.show()
        mService.getPicturesList(search).enqueue(object : Callback<Labels> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Labels>, response: Response<Labels>) {
                labels = response.body() as Labels
                        if (switchCompat.isChecked) {
                            setOneAdapter(labels)
                        } else {
                            setTwoAdapter(labels)
                        }
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Labels>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString("key", editText.text.toString())
    }

}
```

По нажатию на картинку, открывается фрагмент с детальным описанием картинки:

[image: Детальное описание]

```
class FragmentDetails : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var imageUser: ImageView
    private lateinit var textUser: TextView
    private lateinit var textTags: TextView
    private lateinit var textLikes: TextView
    private lateinit var textComments: TextView
    private lateinit var textViews: TextView
    private lateinit var imageSave: ImageView
    private lateinit var imageBack: ImageView


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)
        val hits: Hits?

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_details)
        imageUser = view.findViewById(R.id.image_user_details)
        textUser = view.findViewById(R.id.text_user_details)
        textTags = view.findViewById(R.id.text_tags_details)
        textLikes = view.findViewById(R.id.text_likes_details)
        textComments = view.findViewById(R.id.text_comments_details)
        textViews = view.findViewById(R.id.text_views_details)
        imageSave = view.findViewById(R.id.image_save)
        imageBack = view.findViewById(R.id.image_back)

        textLikes.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.ic_baseline_favorite_24,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )
        textComments.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.ic_baseline_comment_24,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )
        textViews.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.ic_baseline_remove_red_eye_24,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )

        val bundle: Bundle? = arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            hits = bundle.getParcelable("item_key")
            Picasso.get().load(hits?.largeImageURL).into(imageView)
            if (hits?.userImageURL != "") {
                Picasso.get().load(hits?.userImageURL).into(imageUser)
            }
            textUser.text = hits?.user
            textTags.text = hits?.tags
            textLikes.text = hits?.likes
            textViews.text = hits?.views
            textComments.text = hits?.comments

            imageSave.setOnClickListener {
                download(hits!!)
                Snackbar.make(imageSave, "Downloading...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Fail")
        }

        imageBack.setOnClickListener {
            parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
        return view
    }

    private fun download(hits: Hits) {
        val filename = hits.id + ".jpg"
        val dirname = "pixabay"
        val downloadUrlOfImage = hits.largeImageURL
        val direct = File(
            Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                .absolutePath + "/" + dirname + "/"
        )


        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdir()
            Log.d("TAG", "dir created for first time")
        }

        val dm = context?.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val downloadUri: Uri = Uri.parse(downloadUrlOfImage)
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri)
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle(filename)
            .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                File.separator + dirname + File.separator.toString() + filename
            )

        dm.enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

Проблема для меня заключается в том, что по возвращению в прошлый фрагмент, вызывается метод onCreateView и в recyclerview загружаются дефолтные картинки, хотя в текстовом поле значение поиска сохраняется. И когда я получаю значение текстового поля, он выдаёт null, хотя в нём содержится текст, и его видно. Получается, что пользователю нужно снова запустить процесс поиска, чтобы вернуться к картинкам, которые он искал ранее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал производить поиск снова по запуску метода onResume. Но выходит, что стоит просто свернуть приложение, как по возвращению он обновит список (Плохо, если пользователь успел пролистать список вниз), savedInstanceState тоже не помогает.
Как можно этого избежать?

Класс FragmentStateHelper, который я взял из ответа на другой похожий вопрос. К сожалению, он не помог. Его использование ни на что не влияет. Что с ним, что без него. Вставил бы ссылку на тот ответ, но потерял её(

```
class FragmentStateHelper(val fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {

    private val fragmentSavedStates = mutableMapOf<String, Fragment.SavedState?>()
    
    fun restoreState(fragment: Fragment, key: String) {
        fragmentSavedStates[key]?.let { savedState ->
            // We can't set the initial saved state if the Fragment is already added
            // to a FragmentManager, since it would then already be created.
            if (!fragment.isAdded) {
                fragment.setInitialSavedState(savedState)
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun saveState(fragment: Fragment, key: String) {
        // We can't save the state of a Fragment that isn't added to a FragmentManager.
        if (fragment.isAdded ?: false) {
            fragmentSavedStates[key] = fragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а как и где вы получаете текст из поля? вообще было бы неплохо привести код фрагмента

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate Изучали?
И далее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerviews-scroll-position-using-recyclerview-state

Comment: @IR42 Я добавил код фрагментов. Надеюсь, так будет понятнее.

Comment: что за FragmentStateHelper? удалите ```if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getAllPicturesList(editText.text.toString())
        } else {
           stateHelper.restoreState(this, "key")
        }```, должно заработать

Comment: @IR42 Я добавил код этого класса в вопрос. Этот класс предлагался как решение на похожий вопрос. Однако, мне он не помог. При этом, его использование вообще ни на что не повлияло. Как будто, его и нет. Я много экспериментировал с использованием этого класса, но какого-либо результата я не достиг